# Why wasn't there a gunship in the air during the Bergdahl trade?

Tags: international-relations, military, military-law

I hope I don't come off as crazy here, and I wasn't sure if this is the right forum to ask this, but I have a question regarding the Bowe Bergdahl prisoner exchange.

[In the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mr49TsLSnnk) captured by the Taliban, we see that there are many armed men in fully concealing garbs, who are presumably the Taliban, that are involved during the swap. My question is regarding the aftermath of the swap.

We see that the black chopper carrying US forces and Bergdahl fly away safely. How come there wasn't a gunship or drone (that could go relatively undetected to the ground forces below) in the air that would pick off all of the terrorists below once the deal was done? Why didn't the US eliminate these people on the ground? Were they really Taliban men or was something else stopping this sort of plan? Also, could a plan like this, specifically, double crossing the other side, ever have been considered by the US government in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no particular insights into the decision-making process in the US military but one obvious reason would be to avoid threatening any other such exchange that might become necessary in the future.

I would guess it must have been *considered* but at some point you have to recognise that beyond all the rhetoric, it's really a war and there are many reasons why you don't (usually) do something like this in these circumstances. Calling the Taliban “terrorists” or “enemy combatants” might help US officials keep a straight face when they try to justify torture or war crimes but it does not really change the facts on the ground.

Still, I am pretty sure that if there was an overwhelming benefit, the US would do this (and more) and perhaps that's a good thing. But here you have to ask what the purpose would be. Taking out some middle-level Taliban fighters? That does not sound like a goal worthy of risking even a minor damage to your reputation and, especially, to the ability to save US prisoners/hostage through negotiation in the future.